# Select a file without knowing the last five characters of its name in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am using PowerShell to open a PDF file so I can scrape some data out of it.

I am declaring the file path of the string, but the last five characters of the filename are unknown to me. The file resides in a shared folder and the first 10 characters are unique in the filename, so I can use them to identify the file.

How do I select the file using a wild card for the last part of the file?

So far I have:

```
$filePath = "c:temp\" + $currentYear + "\" + "file201520_*****.pdf"
```

Comment: Use `Resolve-Path` cmdlet.

Comment: I don't understand.  What's wrong with `Get-ChildItem`?  What have you tried and why didn't it work?

Comment: The script is ran by a scheduled task daily and the file is identified by the current date (I have edited the code above to show this).  I don't know the ****** section nor can I predict it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `Get-Item`:

```psh
$dirPath  = Join-Path 'C:\temp' $currentYear 
$filePath = Join-Path $dirPath 'file201520_*.pdf'

$file = Get-Item $filePath
```

If the file name contains the current date you can factor that in like this:

```psh
$today = Get-Date -f 'yyyydd'

$dirPath  = Join-Path 'C:\temp' $currentYear 
$filePath = Join-Path $dirPath "file${today}_*.pdf"

$file = Get-Item $filePath
```

Comment: In your code above the * will be part of the filename ie in my case its a 5 digit number, so I need a wild card so using your example I need it to match up the _ and then ignore the rest but still open the file.

Comment: @user2050577 Please provide evidence. `*` *is* a wildcard character, so the above will select the PDF file whose name starts with `file201520_`, provided that prefix is unique in the given directory.

Comment: Apologies, you are correct I missed something else.

Answer (score 1):

"*" is a wildcard that matches zero or more characters. There is another wildcard, "?", that will match exactly one character. So if you specify the file path as

```
$filePath = "c:temp\" + $currentYear + "\" + "file201520_?????.pdf"
```

you should get what you want.

See *[Wildcards](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-wildcards.html)*