# Getting the filename from a partial path in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am using PowerShell to open a [PDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) file where I don't know the full filename of the PDF file.

The following questions assisted me in getting this working and the code below is from that question.

*[Select a file without knowing the last five characters of its name in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30356120)*

```
$dirPath  = Join-Path 'C:\temp' $currentYear 
$filePath = Join-Path $dirPath 'file201520_*.pdf'

$file = Get-Item $filePath
```

How then can I extract its actual full name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will show you the properties of `$File`:

```psh
$file | Format-List *
```

You will see that `$file.Name` will tell you the file's name or `$file.FullName` will give you the name with the complete path.